In Law & Order SVU S24 E2, Grace says something in Spanish to the grandmother. What did they say?
In Grace Muncy's first episode, she says something in Spanish at 12 minutes 50 seconds into the show to the grandmother which seemed to help convince the grandmother into revealing her grandson.
I've search threads about the show her, on reddit, and spoiler/walkthrough. Apple TV subtitles ignores the Spanish bit and download SRT files also ignore it:

294 00:12:49,725 --> 00:12:50,726 He's just running.
295 00:12:50,770 --> 00:12:54,730 [speaking Spanish]
296 00:12:57,037 --> 00:12:59,474 Yeah, why don't you tell us  where
he is

I also tried to use the clip in google audio translation apps and it didn't detect the words as Spanish.
Does anyone know what she said here?

